# regex matching and all optional groups

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble extracting groups when all of them might be optional.

---

**Context (skip to end if you like):**
This is in the context of best-matching a string to a bunch of regex expressions, and seeing which expression has most group matches.

For example, I might have a potential format;

```
1: [A|B] [CD|DE|EF]-[1-1|1-2|2-2|2-3] [G|H]
```

But I expect the user to mistype, or not include spaces or something.

So I might test it against the string

```
A CD-1-1 G
```

and want to get groups

1. A
2. CD
3. 1-1
4. G

but ALSO, for the test string

```
DE-1-9 G
```

I'd like to get

1. 
2. DE
3. 
4. G

---

**So here's my regex to match the following optional groups**

```
[A|B] [CD|DE|EF]-[1-1|1-2|2-2|2-3] [G|H]
```

Regex:

```
(A|B)?(?: *)?(CD|DE|EF)?(?:-|(?: ))?((?:1-(?:1|2))|(?:2-(?:2|3)))?(?: *)?(G|H)?
```

Breaking down how I think this should work;

- (A|B)? - Match an "A" or "B" character (which may or not be there).
- (?: *)? - Match some space characters (which again may not be there), but don't need the group.
- (CD|DE|EF)? - Match "CD" "DE" or "EF" (may or may not be there).
- (?:-|(?: ))? - Match a "-" or some spaces (may or may not be there).
- ((?:1-(?:1|2))|(?:2-(?:2|3)))? - Match [1-[1|2]] or [2-[2|3]] (may or may not be correct/there at all)
- (?: *)? - Match some space characters (which again may not be there), but don't need the group.
- (G|H)? - Match an "G" or "H" character (which may or not be there).

Problem that this **does not match groups I expect** with the test string

```
A CD 1-9 G
```

I expect groups

1. A
2. CD
3. 
4. G

But I get

1. A
2. CD
3. 
4. 

Why is it not matching after the third group?

Comment: Try [`^([AB]?) *(?:(CD|DE|EF)?|\S*)[- ]?(?:(1-[12]|2-[23])?|\S+) *([GH]?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/hR2sC0/1)

Comment: I think Wiktor's pattern works, and to answer your question, it's optional to have `[1-1|1-2|2-2|2-3]`, but then the ` G` would only match if there was nothing in its place. The `1-9` breaks the pattern. Wiktor addresses it by allowing for an empty alternative in each of the central patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using

```
^([AB]?) *(?:(CD|DE|EF)?|[^- ]*)[- ]?(?:(1-[12]|2-[23])?|\S*) *([GH]?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR2sC0/2)

Surely the main point is adding the `$` anchor - end-of-string assertion making the string match up to its end.

Next, as [Paulo Almeida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081569/paulo-almeida) points out [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377299/regex-matching-and-all-optional-groups#comment60372737_36377299), if there is no `1-1` there must be some other subpattern to match, say, `1-9`. Since after `CD` / `DE` / `EF` can be a hyphen or a space, let's match 0+ characters other than space or `-` with `[^ - ]`. Since after `1-1` / `1-2` / `2-2` / `2-3` there can be a space, let's match all non-whitespace characters. There can be more adjustments like this, but that is how the working regex can be written.

I also suggest getting rid of alternations with single characters and turn them into character classes. `(?: *)?` =  `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex101 catches the `G` in Match 2. Try adding the `g`lobal modifier.

Answer (score 0):

This looks sort of like a validation, with almost everything optional.
Still, you'd need some things to help line things up.

First, anchors `^$`. This or some other pseudo-anchors(text) are needed
to give it a start and end to focus the search.

Second, a common optional delimiter between data parts. This gives
it something to consume. A space and dash can be used `[- ]`.

This will line up the parts from left to right. They are all optional.

`^(?=.)[- ]*([AB])?[- ]*(CD|DE|EF)?[- ]*(?:(1-[12]|2-[23])|\d-\d)?[- ]*([GH])?[- ]*$`

Some explanation to go along with it:

```
 ^                             # Beginning of string
 (?= . )                       # Only used to insure not a blank line
 [- ]*                         # Optional specific delimiters
 ( [AB] )?                     # (1), Optional A or B
 [- ]*                         # Optional specific delimiters
 ( CD | DE | EF )?             # (2), Optional CD or DE or EF
 [- ]*                         # Optional specific delimiters
 (?:                           # Optional numb-numb
      ( 1- [12] | 2- [23] )         # (3), Only ones we care about
   |                              # or,
      \d - \d                       # Any numb-numb
 )?
 [- ]*                         # Optional specific delimiters
 ( [GH] )?                     # (4), Optional G or H
 [- ]*                         # Optional specific delimiters
 $                             # End of string
```

All the capture groups are set to optional (not their contents) so it makes
it easy to test if they have data (NULL or length>0 depending on the engine).

Test:

For testing I used the multi-line mode and included all entries as a single
string (if you examine only a single input at a time, don't use this mode).

Input:

```
A CD 1-9 G
DE-1-9 G
A CD-1-1 G
AG
4-8
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 10 ) 
A CD 1-9 G  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 1 ) 
A  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 2 , len 2 ) 
CD  
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 9 , len 1 ) 
G  
-----------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 12 , len 8 ) 
DE-1-9 G  
 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 12 , len 2 ) 
DE  
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 19 , len 1 ) 
G  
-----------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 22 , len 10 ) 
A CD-1-1 G  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 22 , len 1 ) 
A  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 24 , len 2 ) 
CD  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 27 , len 3 ) 
1-1  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 31 , len 1 ) 
G  
-----------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 34 , len 2 ) 
AG  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 34 , len 1 ) 
A  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 35 , len 1 ) 
G  
-----------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 38 , len 3 ) 
4-8  
 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 4 -  NULL
```

Comment: Yet another great answer. Thanks for going through it.

Comment: @THRND - No problem. This is a $20 answer because it gives a technique that can be applied vertically. Quick $2 answers are like, disposable, use once then can't use them again..